# infinite list rendering issue on sencha EXTJS 6

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, sencha-touch

I have infinite lists(by making infinite list property as true in lists).

These list items are not getting rendered, even though there is proper data in store.

And when I tap on the list or do some CSS changes for list, it gets rendered. Can we forcefully render an infinite list from code?

As far as I know there is a problem in infinite list in calculating the required height if the lot of items are nested.

Comment: Please show some sample code, preferably make a Sencha fiddle.

Comment: I had same problem. where was data in store but rows was not rendered. in my case problem was with layout. if your grid is in container specify layout property for container. for example `layout:'fit'`